# how to dynamically add content to tab in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to wpf and c# programming.
What i need to do, is to be able to create a tabControl dynamically in runtime
with data imported from xml files.
So far i have managed to read the data from the xml files
and dynamically create the tabs' headers (but not add the thumbnail in the tab header)...
but i can't figure out how to load the data into tabs...
I want to do something like the screen shot below...
The data loaded into the tabs need to be images along with a tool-tip if possible!
It has to be done in run-time, since the tabs and the data into each tab may change..

anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks!

PS> screen-shot: http://img703.imageshack.us/i/screendn.png/

Answer (score 2):

You can read data from xml file to List collection and bind TabControl to it, like this

```
 <TabControl x:Name="TheTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding XmlData}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TabItem Header="{Binding XmlHeader}">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding xmlContent}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem>
            </DataTemplate>                
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put any control in header of tabitem. TabItem header value is type of object.

Ex:

```
Dim tabitem As TabItem
tabitem.Header = New Button With {.Content = "Button"}
tabcontrol.Items.Add(tabitem)
```